# Java codes to rename file when slider is on or off

Tags: java, xml, swing

I am new to Java! I am trying to create a control panel in Java, that will be populated via xml that will include sliding a slider to "off" and this will rename bgl files to off. Sliding the slider to on will rename the file back to bgl. I have only tried locking but I am ashamed of my codes as I am learning and I really want to learn. I am totally lost!

```
package turbulentDesign;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.Panel;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.Label;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

public class ControlPanel {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ControlPanel window = new ControlPanel();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public ControlPanel() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(245, 245, 220));
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(900, 600);

        Panel products = new Panel();
        products.setBounds(25, 74, 167, 440);
        frame.getContentPane().add(products);


        Panel information = new Panel();
        information.setBounds(198, 74, 342, 447);
        frame.getContentPane().add(information);

        Panel settings = new Panel();
        settings.setBounds(554, 74, 336, 447);
        frame.getContentPane().add(settings);






        JLabel sliderLabel = new JLabel();
        JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 1, 2, 1);
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        sliderLabel.setOpaque(true);
        settings.add(slider);
        settings.add(sliderLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){
            @Override 
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){
                JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();

                if(!source.getValueIsAdjusting()){
                    int rename = (int)source.getValue();
                    if(rename == 1){
                        System.out.println("Fail to rename");
                    }
                    }
                else{
                    File file = new File("/Users/bolaadeyeyeomisade/Documents/ApplicationWorkSpace/DocRename/program.txt");
                    file.renameTo(new File("/Users/bolaadeyeyeomisade/Documents/ApplicationWorkSpace/DocRename/java.txt"));

                }           
        }
        });
        JSlider slider_1 = new JSlider();
        settings.add(slider_1);

    }


    public boolean renameFileTo(File dest){

        File oldName = new File("/ControlPanel/program.xml");
          if(oldName.renameTo(dest)) {
             return true;
          } else {
              return false;
          }     
    }




}
```

Comment: This code is reading in your xml file.  It doesn't seem to be related to any UI code.  Please include code related to the slider, etc...

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the codes

Comment: Sorted!! Updated the codes..